# Why can $x^0$ sometimes be simplified to 1 even when x can equal 0?

Tags: calculus, exponentiation

For example, the Taylor series for $e^x$ is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$. It seems like it should be indeterminate or undefined at $x=0$, since the first term would contain $0^0$, but it's not - the first term is just simplified to $1$.

Edit: answered in Matthew Levy's comment.

Comment: It's just notational simplicity since mathematicians are lazy. We just define $0^0:=1$ for this particular situation. It saves from having to make different cases and write everything out.

Comment: A different answer is that when the exponent is *fixed* to be zero, then the limit that yields a $0^0$ form is actually $1$. This is important in the binomial theorem: $(x+0)^n = x^n {n \choose 0} 0^0$ only works out under the convention $0^0=1$.

Comment: I always thought it was because $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}x^x=1$